# Emberjs should I be using control for this

Tags: model-view-controller, ember.js, ember-data

I'm attempting to build a FedEx style scheduling board. This would look just like a week view on a calendar but instead of days it would have driver columns. The trips should be able to drag and drop between columns and appear at the correct height for the time.

I'm abstracting to ensure I have the correct logic before tackling the actual code.

[image: white board illustrating controllers in the templates]

So lets say I have a date on the index controller. Selecting a date will load the schedule for that date. The schedule contains drivers and each driver has trips.

What controller do I use to handle the trips? The content is different depending on the column but each column needs to be visible. Also I need to add events to these which presumably uses a view but ember will only ever load a view once. I'm sure I've just missed something fundamental but all the examples of ember apps I've found involve clicking a list item and loading in a view for that.

Am I thinking about my application with the correct mvc setup? Should I be approaching the problem differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ember RC1 [introduced a notion of an itemController](http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/02/15/ember-1-0-rc.html) when iterating through a list in handlebars:

```
{{each trip in tripList itemController='trips'}}
    {{view YourApp.TripView}}
{{/each}}
```

That way each instance of your trip can have its own trip controller.  We're doing something similar, and this actually saved us a lot of work.

Comment: Oh my god. This is exactly what I'm looking for. That way I can just use each over the drivers trips. Does this mean that there will be more then one tripsController? Are they all long lived?

Comment: Yes.  Each iteration through the {{each}} helper will set your context to be the new TripController with the current trip set as that controller's content.

Comment: Also - not quite sure what you mean by "long lived" - they are useful for the entire iteration through that each block, and if you want you can pass them as arguments to actions like `{{action "fooAction" controller}}`